# includes/joins case in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a `habtm` relationship between my `Product` and `Category` model.
I'm trying to write a query that searches for products with minimum of 2 categories.

I got it working with the following code:

```
p = Product.joins(:categories).group("product_id").having("count(product_id) > 1")
p.length # 178
```

When iterating on it though, for each time I call `product.categories`, it will do a new call to the database - not good. **I want to prevent these calls and have the same result**. Doing more research I've seen that I could include (`includes`)  my `categories` table and it would load all the table in memory so it's not necessary to call the database again when iterating. So I got it working with the following code:

```
p2 = Product.includes(:categories).joins(:categories).group("product_id").having("count(product_id) > 1")
p2.length # 178 - I compared and the objects are the same as last query
```

Here come's what I am confused about:

```
p.first.eql? p2.first # true
p.first.categories.eql? p2.first.categories # false
p.first.categories.length # 2
p2.first.categories.length # 1
```

Why with the `includes` query I get the right objects but I don't get the `categories` relationship right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has something to do with the `group` method. Your `p2` only contains the first category for each product.

You could break this up into two queries:

```
product_ids = Product.joins(:categories).group("product_id").having("count(product_id) > 1").pluck(:product_id)

result = Product.includes(:categories).find(product_ids)
```

Yeah, you hit the database twice, but at least you don't go to the database when you're iterating.

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thank you very much @Jason

Answer (score 1):

You must know that `includes` doesn't play well with joins (`joins` will just suppress the former).

Also When you `include` an association `ActiveRecord` figures out if it'll use `eager_load` (with a left join) or `preload` (with a separate query). Includes is just a wrapper for one of those 2.

The thing is `preload` plays well with joins ! So you can do this :

```
products = Product.preload(:categories). # this will trigger a separate query
               joins(:categories).       # this will build the relevant query
               group("products.id").
               having("count(product_id) > 1").
               select("products.*")
```

Note that this will also hit the database twice, but you will not have any O(n) query.

Comment: Love your solution and explanation @charlysisto.